# Syntax for implementing an indexer in C++/CLI in the .CPP file

Tags: .net, c++-cli

I want to implement an indexed property in a managed class written in C++/CLI.

I have no problems defining it inline.  Here's a dummy implementation of an indexer that takes and returns an int:

```
public ref class MyClass
{
    property int default[int]    
    { 
        int    get(int idx) {return 0; }
        void   set(int idx, int value) {  }
    }
}
```

But what I want to do is merely declare them in the header and implement them in the .CPP file.  Unfortunately I cannot figure out the syntax how to implement these functions fully in the .CPP file.  I can't get the syntax right and the MS examples I can find all define them inline.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: int MyClass::default::get(int idx) {} and void MyClass::default::set(int idx, int value) {}

Comment: Coulda sworn I'd tried that.   Clearly not.  Appreciated