# Creating an array from already created labels

Tags: visual-studio, c++-cli

I am using Visual Studio 2022, C++

I would like to create an array of already created labels. The reason for this is printing on labels, which are in another form, through a for loop, in order to shorten the code, according to `labels[i]` labels[0] - label1, labels[1] - label2...

postavke.cpp(Form2), kontrolna is Form1

```
kontrolna^ kontrolna_name = gcnew kontrolna();
    
    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {

        kontrolna_name->labels[i]->Text = " ";
    }
```

Does anyone have an idea how to perform this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51409462/syntax-for-implementing-an-indexer-in-c-cli-in-the-cpp-file

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to use a CLI array. You can create an array of labels as follows
`cli::array<System::Windows::Forms::Label^ >^ Labels = gcnew cli::array<System::Windows::Forms::Label^>(4) { label1, label2, label3, label4 };`

where 4 is the number of elements in the array. Above utilized an initialization list but it can be also be declared empty and populated after such as

```
cli::array<System::Windows::Forms::Label^ >^ Labels = gcnew cli::array<System::Windows::Forms::Label^>(4); 
Labels[0] = label1;
Labels[1] = label2;
Labels[2] = label3;
Labels[3] = label4;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I managed that part, but even though there are no bugs in the code and the program works, the labels from the second form (kontrolna) do not change values.

I took advantage

kontrolna^ kontrolna_name = gcnew kontrolna();

....

kontrolna_name->labels[i]->Text = " ";
Should something be changed? I linked the header files normally.